# Copying object without dope sheet data

Tags: transforms, dopesheet

How do I make a copy of an object without coying any of its dope sheet data? So the new object should have an empty dope sheet.

Answer (score 0):

After copying, you can unlink the action fron the object, by turning the dopesheet into an action editor and pressing the X button near the action name to unlink it.

[image]